# Processing huge data from sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, yield-return

I have a stored procedure (SQL Server 2016) which currently returns 100K to 200K rows based on the parameters to that SP.

Each row can be a size of 100KB to 200KB. So total size can be around 10GB to 20GB.

My client(background job) has to call this SP and process all rows and send it to another client.

What is the best approach to handle such scenarios?

Currently I am thinking of using streaming enumerator using yield.

Get the record whenever the 'datareader.Read()' read a row and process it and send it to other client.

```
dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();                    
while (dataReader.Read())
{
    obj = new SomeClass();

    // prepare Someclass

    yield return obj;
}
```

Is this approach sufficient to handler such large data?

Is there any better approach to it? (Such as multi threading etc.)

If so how should I approach to it. Any pointers to refer?

Edit: SP has multiple joins and runs couple of times in a day.

Comment: Are you doing joins in your SQL stored procedure and returning data from multiple tables? How often does this process run?

Comment: How about to update your SP to allow data pagination?

Comment: @Jonathan.Hickey SP has multiple joins and runs couple of times in a day. Added same in original question.

Comment: @PSR does the SP return duplicate data based off the those joins, explains would be like StatusID, StatusName, StasusDiscription, LanguageId, LanguageCode, LanguageName etc?

Comment: @Jonathan.Hickey It will not return duplicate data. It is filtered at SP level.

Comment: My experience has been to reduce the amount of data coming back as much as possible... And have lookups in code that map to the object. So my aim in answering the question would be to reduce the 100kb - 200kb row size as much as possible.

Comment: For such huge quantities of data, i'd start by looking if the SP can be altered to accept additional parameters from the client to further filter and reduce the amount of return data at the SP level.
Then, if I have it sufficiently reduced, i'd store it in a cash on the application memory (which does not seem realistic to me for the current 10-20 GB result set)

Comment: @PSR when I talk about duplicate data, it's at column level not row level (although getting rid of duplicate rows helps). Do your filters change what columns come back?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I believe that it represents a good scenario for implementing an SSIS (Integration Services) which can manage and write the final results into a CSV file and allow the customer to exchange it.

Comment: That is not an option in my case.